# Confusion on ektron persona management

Tags: ektron

i have created a custom connection in dxh but that is not available on persona management site. from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paKiIaDWndw) video i understand that i have to create a class library for my custom connection. Is there any demo code available for this custom library?

i am stuck with the login management of dxh and persona, and how is this attributes working?

my code

```
using Attribute = Ektron.PersonaManagement.Common.Attribute;
public class ETPersona : PersonaAttributeProvider
{
     public override IEnumerable<Attribute> GetAttributes()
    {
        return new List<Attribute>() { 
            new Attribute() { 
                DataSource = "test", 
                DataSourceId = "test", 
                Id = "test", 
                Name = new LocalizableText("test","test"), 
                Type =FieldType.String,
                Options = new List<LocalizableText>(){new LocalizableText("test","test")} 
            } 
        };
    }
    public override UserAttributeData GetUserAttributeData(VisitorContext context)
    {
       return new UserAttributeData()
        {
            Attributes = new List<UserAttribute>() { new UserAttribute() { } },
            HaveUserData = true,
            UserKey = ""
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see Ektron's forum discussion here for information:
http://developer.ektron.com/Forums/?v=t&t=1975